# $f$ is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour $C$ and has a zero of order 2 or more at $\infty$. Show$\int_Cf(z)~dz=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f$ is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour $C$ and has a zero of order 2 or more at $\infty$, then $\int_Cf(z)~dz=0$. Does this integral vanish if we merely assume that f has a simple zero at $\infty$?

I only get $f(\frac{1}{z})=z^mg(z)$ $(m\ge2)\ and\ g(0)\ne 0)$ and $f(\frac{1}{z}) $ is analytic on a disk $|z|\le r$ for some $r$.