# If $f$ is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour $C$ and has a zero of order 2 or more at $\infty$, then $\int_Cf(z)\,dz=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

**My Goal:**
I want to prove that if $f$ is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour $C$ and has a zero of order 2 or more at $\infty$, then $\int_Cf(z)\,dz=0$.

Here is my attempt at my work and where I got stuck.

**My Work:**
Denote $w = \frac 1 z$. Since the zero is at $\infty$, then $f(\frac 1 w)$ has a zero of order $m \geq 2$ at $w = 0$. As such we can write $f(\frac 1 w) = w^m h(w), m \geq 2$ for some $h(w$) that is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour, and also analytic at $0$.

Now since $z = \frac 1 w$ then $\frac {dz}{dw} = -\frac 1 {w^2}$ and we have the integral

$$\int_Cf(z)\,dz = -\int_Cf(1/w)\frac{dw}{w^2} = -\int_C w^{m-2}h(w)\,dw.$$

I'd like to perhaps apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem, but I'm not sure how to do that, since it doesn't seem like the assumptions about simple connected domains and analyticity hold here - after all, we only knew that $f$ was analytic on and *outside* the contour, not inside. How can I finish up?

**Note:** This is a repeat of [$f$ is analytic on and outside the simple closed contour $C$ and has a zero of order 2 or more at $\infty$. Show$\int_Cf(z)~dz=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985457/f-is-analytic-on-and-outside-the-simple-closed-contour-c-and-has-a-zero-of-o), which received no answers.

Comment: Hint: If $g(z)$ is analytic inside and on $C$ then $\int_C \frac {g(z)} {z^{k}}dz=0$ for $ k \geq 2$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I was wondering why this is true, by Cauchy's integral formula wouldn't this be equal to $g''(0) \cdot 2\pi i$ which is not necessarily  $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $z_0$ inside the domain enclosed by $C$, and take the Laurent series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{(z-z_0)^n}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(z-z_0)^n}$$

Then $$\int_{C} f(z)dz=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\int_C \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^n}dz=0$$

since the residue of $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^n}$ vanishes at $z=z_0$.
There are some technical details to be worried about, such as $C$ needs to be piecewise $C^1$ or at least rectifiable for the integral to be defined, but nothing too serious.

Here is another approach, using only the Cauchy integral formula. By the given condition, $g(w):=f(\frac{1}{w}+z_0)$ is analytic inside $C'=\{w=\frac{1}{z-z_0} : z\in C\}$ that encloses $0$, where $z_0$ is any point enclosed by $C$. Therefore by the Cauchy integral formula (or rather [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://%20Cauchy%27s%20differentiation%20formula)) $$g'(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C'} \frac{g(w)}{w^2}dw=0$$ $$\Rightarrow\int_{C'}\frac{f(\frac{1}{w}+z_0)}{w^2}dw=0 \Rightarrow \int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{1/(z-z_0)^2}d(\frac{1}{z-z_0})=0\Rightarrow\int_C f(z)dz=0$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I have not learned residues in class yet, so I am wondering if there is an alternative approach to this that would not involve residue theorem?

Comment: Residue theorem is extremely easy to understand in this particular case. You can directly compute that $\int_C \frac{1}{z^k}dz=0$ for $k\ge 2$ when $C$ is the unit circle, and for arbitrary $C$ that encloses $0$, just deform it to be the unit circle, which won't change the integral, since $1/z^k$ is analytic on the punched plane.

Comment: Annother way would be just the two comments between you two earlier. I put down some details but I don't feel it's as intuitive as the solution using the series expansion.

Comment: thanks for the details! I think I'm missing something obvious, but how do we know that $g''(0) = 0$ or that the integral over $C'$ is equal to $0$? If $C'$ encloses $0$ then $g(z)/z^2$ is not analytic everywhere in the domain containing $C'$, so Cauchy's Integral Theorem does not apply?

Comment: I tried to show that $g''(0) = 0$ using the fact that $g(w) = w^m h(w)$ where $h(0) \neq 0$. Taking the product rule twice and $m = 2$ for an example, we have that $g''(w) = w^2 h''(w) + 2wh'(w) + 2wh'(w) + 2h(w)$. Plugging in $w = 0$, this evaluates to $g''(0) = 2h(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. You're right about $g''(0)$, and I do mean $g'(0)=0$, and technically I'm using the Cauchy's differentiation formula instead of the raw Cauchy's integral formula, but they are usually established at the same time. Also I improved the answer in case $C$ doesn't enclose $0$, so we still have to pick a $z_0$ enclosed by $C$.